# NoClassDefFoundError in RAD

Tags: java, rad

I am encountering the following error in my app. upon starting it:

```
    [3/26/12 13:05:26:109 SGT] 0000001a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.test.Delegate (initialization failure)]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.Delegate (initialization failure)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
        at com.test.workflow.Workflow.<init>(Workflow.java:28)
        at com.actions.Action.<init>(Action.java:54)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1345)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:119)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:150)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:387)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:186)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:458)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1062)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:759)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: com.delta.ecom.exception.WrapperSystemException: Error converting Source to Object
    at com.delta.ecom.util.callwrapper.DataTransformer.convertSourceToObject(DataTransformer.java:443)
    at com.delta.ecom.util.callwrapper.CallServiceDaoImpl.loadResource(CallServiceDaoImpl.java:291)
    at com.delta.ecom.util.callwrapper.CallServiceDaoImpl.<init>(CallServiceDaoImpl.java:69)
    at com.delta.ecom.util.callwrapper.ServiceLocatorImpl.<init>(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:27)
    at com.delta.ecom.util.callwrapper.CallWrapper.<init>(CallWrapper.java:43)
    at com.delta.ecom.trips.delegate.BaseTripsDelegate.<clinit>(BaseTripsDelegate.java:21)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.MalformedURLException]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:221)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:237)
    at com.delta.ecom.util.callwrapper.DataTransformer.convertSourceToObject(DataTransformer.java:437)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:613)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:476)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:425)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:219)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.test.com.ecom.exception.WrapperSystemException: Error converting Source to Object
    at com.test.com.ecom.util.caller.DataTransformer.convertSourceToObject(DataTransformer.java:443)
    at com.test.com.ecom.util.caller.CallServiceDaoImpl.loadResource(CallServiceDaoImpl.java:291)
    at com.test.com.ecom.util.caller.CallServiceDaoImpl.<init>(CallServiceDaoImpl.java:69)
    at com.test.com.ecom.util.caller.ServiceLocatorImpl.<init>(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:27)
    at com.test.com.ecom.util.caller.caller.<init>(caller.java:43)
    at com.test.com.ecom.trips.delegate.BaseTripsDelegate.<clinit>(BaseTripsDelegate.java:21)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.MalformedURLException]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:221)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:198)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:237)
    at com.test.com.ecom.util.caller.DataTransformer.convertSourceToObject(DataTransformer.java:437)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:613)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:476)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:425)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:219)
    ... 58 more
```

How can i resolve this error? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.Delegate` and has nothing to do with `J9VMInternals`.  You must read the stack trace carefully to extract the significant information.  This likely means you are missing a jar on your classpath.